# Extending core class in Kohana 3.1

Tags: php, kohana

I have written file form.php in application/classes/form.php

```
 <?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Form extends Kohana_Form {

  public static function input($name, $value = NULL, array $attributes = NULL) {
    // Set the input name
    $attributes['name'] = $name;
    // Set the input value
    $attributes['value'] = $value;
    if (!isset($attributes['id'])) {
      $attributes['id']= $value;
    }
    if (!isset($attributes['type'])) {
      // Default type is text
      $attributes['type'] = 'text';
    }    
    return '<input' . HTML::attributes($attributes) . ' />';
  }

}

?>
```

when I used form::input this function is calling but it is not applying id attribute on the element . 
what is wrong in my code ?

Usage example

```
echo  form::input('date', $cd->year );
```

o/p

```
<input type="text" name="date">
```

Comment: As a tip, you can always call the parent function so you don't have repetition.

Comment: thanks I modified my function to have parent input call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried your code and it worked as expected. Double check that the `$value` argument (`$cd->year` in your case) isn't `NULL`.

`HTML::attributes()` will skip attributes that have a `NULL` value; your custom input method adds an id equal to value, so if value is `NULL` id will be too and it will not be rendered as an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
class Form extends Kohana_Form {

    public static function input($name, $value = NULL, array $attributes = NULL)
    {
        if ( empty($attributes['id']))
        {
            $attributes['id']= $name; // not value
        }

        return parent::input($name, $value, $attributes);
    }

}
```